# Prototype OO-style of my THREE.JS application

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, prototypal-class-design

For several months I'm working with JavaScript and `THREE.JS` library. Firstly I dislike the prototype-based programming because I have to work a lot of with class-oriented languages, where any class is represented as the type and there is a strict separation between declaration and behavior of program design.

But, I understood that prototype-based way is fine for JavaScript, just because it's normally for this way of web-development.

So I want to show you my source code.  I'm doing a project for my work and have a positive resolution to show you the following sources:

http://jsfiddle.net/naFLN/

PS: If you have criticism about my code, please explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

```
/*
* License: Proprietary commercial software
* GC3D, Geocentre consulting 3D, 2013-2014(c)
* Developer: Oleg Orlov A
* http://geocenter-consulting.ru
*/

'use strict';

var GC3D = { Version: '1.0.2' };

GC3D.Enums = {
    renderer: {
        id: 0,
        type: THREE.WebGLRenderer
    },
    camera: {
        id: 1,
        type: THREE.PerspectiveCamera,
        fov: 45,
        aspect: window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        near: 1,
        far: 10000
    },
    scene: {
        id: 2,
        type: THREE.Scene
    }
};


GC3D.Camera = function( settings ) {
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        settings.fov,
        settings.aspect,
        settings.near,
        settings.far
    );
};
GC3D.Camera.prototype.get = function() {
    return this.camera;
};


GC3D.Light = function( color, intensity, distance ) {
    this.light = new THREE.PointLight(
        color,
        intensity,
        distance
    );
};
GC3D.Light.prototype.get = function() {
    return this.light;
};


GC3D.Cube = function( properties ) {
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 
        properties.width,
        properties.height,
        properties.depth,
        properties.widthSegments,
        properties.heightSegments,
        properties.depthSegments
    );
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: properties.color,
        wireframe: properties.wireframe
    });
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        this.geometry,
        this.material
    );
    this.mesh.position.set(
        properties.position.x,
        properties.position.y,
        properties.position.z
    );
};
GC3D.Cube.prototype.get = function() {
    return this.mesh;
};
GC3D.Cube.prototype.setPosition = function( newPosition ) {
    this.mesh.position.set(
        newPosition.x,
        newPosition.y,
        newPosition.z
    );
};
GC3D.Cube.prototype.setPositionAxisValue = function( axis, value ) {
    switch( axis ) {
        case 'x':
            this.mesh.position.x = value;
            break;
        case 'y':
            this.mesh.position.y = value;
            break;
        case 'z':
            this.mesh.position.z = value;
            break;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
};
GC3D.Cube.prototype.movePosition = function( newPosition ) {
    if ( newPosition.x.direction === '+' ) this.mesh.position.x += newPosition.x;
    else if ( newPosition.x.direction === '-' ) this.mesh.position.x -= newPosition.x;

    if ( newPosition.y.direction === '+' ) this.mesh.position.y += newPosition.y;
    else if ( newPosition.y.direction === '-' ) this.mesh.position.y -= newPosition.y;

    if ( newPosition.z.direction === '+' ) this.mesh.position.z += newPosition.z;
    else if ( newPosition.z.direction === '-' ) this.mesh.position.z -= newPosition.z;
};
GC3D.Cube.prototype.movePositionAxisValue = function( axis, direction, value ) {
    switch( [ axis, direction].join( "" ) ) {
        case 'x+':
            this.mesh.position.x += value;
            break;
        case 'y+':
            this.mesh.position.y += value;
            break;
        case 'z+':
            this.mesh.position.z += value;
            break;
        case 'x-':
            this.mesh.position.x -= value;
            break;
        case 'y-':
            this.mesh.position.y -= value;
            break;
        case 'z-':
            this.mesh.position.z -= value;
            break;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
};


GC3D.Utils = function() {
    this.renderer = undefined;
    this.scene = undefined;
    this.camera = undefined;
};
GC3D.Utils.prototype.get = function() {
    var utils = {
        renderer: this.renderer,
        scene: this.scene,
        camera: this.camera
    };
    return utils;
};
GC3D.Utils.prototype.setObject = function( properties ) {
    switch( properties.type ) {
        case THREE.WebGLRenderer:
            this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                alpha: true,
                wireframe: false
            });
            break;
        case THREE.Scene:
            this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            break;
        case THREE.PerspectiveCamera:
            this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                properties.fov,
                properties.aspect,
                properties.near,
                properties.far
            );
            break;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
};
GC3D.Utils.prototype.getObject = function( type ) {
    switch( type ) {
        case THREE.WebGLRenderer:
            return this.renderer;
        case THREE.Scene:
            return this.scene;
        case THREE.PerspectiveCamera:
            return this.camera;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
};
GC3D.Utils.prototype.renderScene = function() {
    // about bind()
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
    requestAnimationFrame( GC3D.Utils.prototype.renderScene.bind( this ) );
    this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );

    // for test purpose only
    this.scene.children.filter(function( item ) {
        if ( item instanceof THREE.Mesh ) item.rotation.x += 0.02;
    });
    //
};
GC3D.Utils.prototype.setCameraPosition = function( camera, newPosition ) {
    if ( camera instanceof THREE.Camera ) camera.position.set( newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z );
    else return -1;
};
GC3D.Utils.prototype.setCameraViewOnObject = function( camera, object ) {
    if ( camera instanceof THREE.Camera && object instanceof THREE.Mesh) this.camera.lookAt( object );
    else return -1;
};
GC3D.Utils.prototype.createCube = function( properties ) {  
    var cube = new GC3D.Cube( properties );
    return cube;
};
GC3D.Utils.prototype.addGeometricObject = function( properties ) {
    switch( properties.type ) {
        case GC3D.Cube:
            var cube = this.createCube( properties );
            this.scene.add( cube.mesh );
            return cube;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
};


GC3D.Application = function() {
    this.utils = new GC3D.Utils();
};
GC3D.Application.prototype.build = function() {
    this.utils.setObject( GC3D.Enums.renderer );
    this.utils.setObject( GC3D.Enums.scene );
    this.utils.setObject( GC3D.Enums.camera );

    // for test purpose only
    var cubeProperties = {
        type: GC3D.Cube,
        width: 1,
        height: 1,
        depth: 1,
        segments: {
            width: 1,
            height: 1,
            depth: 1
        },
        color: 0xff0000,
        wireframe: false,
        position: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            z: 0
        }
    };
    var cube = this.utils.addGeometricObject( cubeProperties );
    this.utils.setCameraPosition( this.utils.camera, { x: 3, y: 3, z: 3 } );
    this.utils.setCameraViewOnObject( this.utils.camera, cube.mesh );
    //

    this.utils.renderScene();
};


window.onload = function() {
    var application = new GC3D.Application();
    application.build();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

All in all, that is some pretty impressive code, I only have some minor comments.

- Instead of returning -1, I would suggest to simply throw a

  ```
  new Exception('informative message')
  ```
- This :

  ```
  GC3D.Cube.prototype.setPositionAxisValue = function( axis, value ) {
      switch( axis ) {
          case 'x':
              this.mesh.position.x = value;
              break;
          case 'y':
              this.mesh.position.y = value;
              break;
          case 'z':
              this.mesh.position.z = value;
              break;
          default:
              return -1;
      }
  };
  ```

  could be

  ```
  GC3D.Cube.prototype.setPositionAxisValue = function( axis, value ) {
      if( this.mesh.position[axis] ){
          this.mesh.position[axis] = value;
      }
      else
      { 
          throw new Exception('Axis ' + axis + ' does not exist');
      }
  };
  ```

  This leaves a tiny window open to trouble; if axis is a variable name that position has which is not x,y,z, then this approach would not detect that
- This :

  ```
  GC3D.Cube.prototype.movePosition = function( newPosition ) {
      if ( newPosition.x.direction === '+' ) this.mesh.position.x += newPosition.x;
      else if ( newPosition.x.direction === '-' ) this.mesh.position.x -= newPosition.x;

      if ( newPosition.y.direction === '+' ) this.mesh.position.y += newPosition.y;
      else if ( newPosition.y.direction === '-' ) this.mesh.position.y -= newPosition.y;

      if ( newPosition.z.direction === '+' ) this.mesh.position.z += newPosition.z;
      else if ( newPosition.z.direction === '-' ) this.mesh.position.z -= newPosition.z;
  };
  ```

  could be

  ```
  GC3D.Cube.prototype.movePosition = function( newPosition ) {
      this.mesh.position.x += +( newPosition.x.direction + newPosition.x );
      this.mesh.position.y += +( newPosition.y.direction + newPosition.y );
      this.mesh.position.z += +( newPosition.z.direction + newPosition.z );            
  };
  ```

  This uses the fact that +(string) will convert that string to a signed number. Note that this is still copy pasted code, so you could consider a helper function for this, but I don't that see that as imperative. You could for example also think about calling `movePositionAxisValue()` as your helper function.
- This piece

  ```
  GC3D.Cube.prototype.movePositionAxisValue = function( axis, direction, value ) {
      switch( [ axis, direction].join( "" ) ) {
          case 'x+':
              this.mesh.position.x += value;
              break;
          case 'y+':
              this.mesh.position.y += value;
              break;
          case 'z+':
              this.mesh.position.z += value;
              break;
          case 'x-':
              this.mesh.position.x -= value;
              break;
          case 'y-':
              this.mesh.position.y -= value;
              break;
          case 'z-':
              this.mesh.position.z -= value;
              break;
          default:
              return -1;
      }
  };
  ```

  could be

  ```
  GC3D.Cube.prototype.movePositionAxisValue = function( axis, direction, value ) {
      if( this.mesh.position[axis] ){
        this.mesh.position[axis] += +( direction + value );
        if( isNaN( this.mesh.position[axis] ) ){
            throw new Exception( 'Could not add' + +( direction + value ) + ' to ' + axis + ' axis' );
        }
      } else {
        throw new Exception( 'Axis ' + axis + ' does not exist' );
      }
  }
  ```

  using the same `+( )` trick as in the previous point, I would probably consider a templating function if I were to throw informative exceptions in every function ;)

All in all, very decent code, my points are just suggestion, well done.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the deleted question? This most likely can be corrected.

Comment: I've created another question on codereview, but people again has closed it... Don't understand why... Despite on this pity situation, I want tell you, that mostly I'm interested exactly in your review and opinion. I think, you're a great professional. So, please visit the website site of my 3D WebGL library http://magesi.ru, I won't provide any other links, because all required information is on website. There are specification, how-to manual, sources. I want to hear you professional mark for my project. Please contact me by email: oleg@amegas.ru or add me to skype, brightstar.amegas